# Invoking getter when window.Element.prototype.className called

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

I'm trying to invoke a getter on each call to Element.className.
I've come out with that:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.Element.prototype, "className", {

        get(value){
            console.log(value);
            debugger;
        },
        set(value){
            console.log(value);
            debugger;
        }

    });
```

but for some reason it doesn't work.
when i'm calling somenode.className i'm not invoking the getter.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` is a value of the instance, therefore it won't be looked up in the prototype, but in the object itself:

```
lookup -->  Instance --> Prototype
              innerHTML      querySelector
              className      querySelectorAll
              id
              ...                        ...
```

You would have to define the getter/setter on every instance you work with.

Comment: Oh i get it so i need to actually replace : "window.Element.prototype" with "Mynode" right?

Comment: Any chance i can do this differently? maybe add this getter higher up so when the instance is created it will already contain my getter

Comment: @avi for that you would have to override the `Element` constructor and I'm not sure if it works in all cases then...

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot!